# What do the `<extra_idx>` tokens in T5 mean?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm using the mT5 model from HuggingFace Transformers to perform some conditional generation and apply it to text classification.

I noticed that whatever the T5 model generates (and before it's trained sufficiently) it usually generates special tokens that look like `<extra_id0>` or `<extra_id1>`. These tokens aren't contained in `T5Tokenizer.special_tokens` either and I'm wondering what they mean.

I looked at the [HuggingFace page for T5](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/t5#training) and it seems like these are special tokens that are used during MLM training? Is that correct?

I couldn't find any details about these tokens in the original paper or anywhere else online strangely enough. Does anybody know what the meaning of these tokens are? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The <extra_id_0> and <extra_id_1> tokens are part of the T5 tokenizer's extra_ids vocabulary, used as sentinel tokens for masking parts of the input that the model needs to predict. These tokens are indexed from the end of the vocabulary to the beginning. You can specify the number of masked tokens to use in the tokenizer.

```
extra_ids (:obj:`int`, `optional`, defaults to 100):
        Add a number of extra ids added to the end of the vocabulary for use as sentinels. These tokens are
        accessible as "<extra_id_{%d}>" where "{%d}" is a number between 0 and extra_ids-1. Extra tokens are
        indexed from the end of the vocabulary up to beginning ("<extra_id_0>" is the last token in the vocabulary
        like in T5 preprocessing see `here
        <https://github.com/google-research/text-to-text-transfer-transformer/blob/9fd7b14a769417be33bc6c850f9598764913c833/t5/data/preprocessors.py#L2117>`__).
```

In the output, the text between <extra_id0> and <extra_id1> represents the output for the first mask, and so on. It's important to note that T5 might not be the best choice for the masked language modeling task, as discussed in this document [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3985). You can also visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75977316/how-to-use-output-from-t5-model-to-replace-masked-tokens-in-input-sequence) page on Stackoverflow for a similar question.