# How to use output from T5 model to replace masked tokens in input sequence

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, generative-pretrained-transformer

I'm working with the T5 model from the Hugging Face Transformers library and I have an input sequence with masked tokens that I want to replace with the output generated by the model. Here's the [code](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/t5#inference).

```
from transformers import T5Tokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration

tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-small")
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("t5-small")

input_data = "The <extra_id_0> walks in <extra_id_1> park"
input_ids = tokenizer(input_data, return_tensors="pt").input_ids

sequence_ids = model.generate(input_ids)
output_sequences = tokenizer.batch_decode(sequence_ids)
output_sequences
```

This code produces the following output:

```
['<pad><extra_id_0> park offers<extra_id_1> the<extra_id_2> park.</s>']
```

What I want to do is replace the masked tokens `<extra_id_0>` and `<extra_id_1>` in the input sequence with the corresponding output tokens from the model, so that the final output is:

```
The park offers walks in the park.
```

I'm hoping someone can help me with the code to achieve this.

Notice that this is the correspondence:

```
mask in input_data -> answer in output_sequences
<extra_id_0> -> <extra_id_0> park offers (so we extract 'park offers' only)
<extra_id_1> -> <extra_id_1> the  (so we extract 'the' only)
```

Answer (score 5):

The t5 model considers tokens which begin with <extra_id as potential mask tokens. As written in the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/t5#training)

"Each sentinel token represents a unique mask token for this sentence and should start with <extra_id_0>, <extra_id_1>, … up to <extra_id_99>"

In the output, you can consider the text between <extra_id_0> and <extra_id_1> as your output for the mask_0, the text between <extra_id_1> and <extra_id_2> as your output for the mask 1 and so on.

To extract this from your generated output, you can use the following code snippet. This will take the number of masks as input and return a list of string as output where each element represents the text predicted for the corresponding mask.

```
def extract_text(text,num_masks=1):
    list_of_text = []
    for i in range(num_masks):
        prev_id = '<extra_id_' + str(i) + '>'
        curr_id = '<extra_id_' + str(i+1) + '>'
        st_token_index = text.index(prev_id)
        end_token_index = text.index(curr_id)
        list_of_text.append(text[st_token_index+12:end_token_index])
    return list_of_text
```

Also, you should note that t5 is not really the best choice for the masked language modelling task as discussed [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3985). Models like BERT are specifically trained for these type of tasks and can directly be used with the fill mask pipeline from huggingface

```
from transformers import pipeline
nlp_fill = pipeline('fill-mask')
```